# My view controller in storyboard will not connect to the viewcontroller.h file or the .m

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm sort of new to xCode so i really don't know much about it. I'm having a problem with my .h and .m files. when I control click on of the view or the pan gesture recognizers, it wont connect. It's been two days and I still don't know. I do have multiple view controllers, but I wanted to make a slide-out menu drawer like the one on the Facebook app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you forget the class name?

[image]

Comment: no, but I did now. But it's still not connecting @Ty_

Comment: tried it on the gesture view, it still wouldn't connect @Ty_

Comment: Did set the class name as the same name as your vewcontroller.m and .h name

Comment: What is the name of you .m and .h file?

Answer (score 0):

check if the target actionof the .m file of objective-c class is checked in the attribute or identity inspector. if it is not checked the make it checked. hope it works...

Answer (score -1):

If you are just looking for a library that does the slide in behavior as Facebook and others take a look at: https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/AMSlideMenu
or follow Ray Wenderlich's tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path